# Creating a function that accepts a data frame and returns N row with largest values

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to create a function that would  take a python pandas dataframe and return the nth row with the highest value available. I found the  Pandas nlargest function can take more than one variable to order the top rows.I used it and  came up with the function below:

```
def largestvalue(df, x):
    lar = df.nlargest(x, ['AGI', 'COSTT4_A'])
    return lar
```

Now in this function I specified the columns I wanted the function to select the largest x number of rows from. It sort of worked as below:

```
largestvalue(df_merged,2)
```

[FunctionResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIi1e.png)

However, I was wondering what I would need to do to provide the user with a function that could allow him to specify the column by either inputting the column name or location number for the chosen data frame. So that he could not only specify the dataframe and the number of rows but also the columns of interest

-Hassan

Answer (score 0):

You can use arguments in your function definition that allow choosing the number of rows and columns.

```
def largestvalue(df, num_of_rows, cols):
    
    return df.nlargest(num_of_rows, cols) 

data = {'AAA':  [3, 8, 2, 1],
        'BBB':  [5, 4, 7, 2],
        'CCC':  [2, 5, 6, 4]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

lar = largestvalue(df, 1, ['AAA', 'BBB'])
```